# Handling boolean values for String parameters in Powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

Using Powershell I'd like to call my script as follows:

```
myscript.ps1 -device1 enable -device2 disable -device3 enable
```

Each `device` paramenter is defined as `String` followed by a `bool` value.

```
param(
  [string] $device1,
  [string] $device2,
  [string] $device3
)
```

Does PowerShell support this with some predefined functions or parameters or would you implement this in a totally different way? I'd like to avoid a parsing for `enable` and `disable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would implement this using a `switch`:

```
param(
  [switch] $device1,
  [switch] $device2,
  [switch] $device3
)
```

So you can invoke your script using:

```
myscript.ps1 -device1 -device3
```

Comment: This would mean that e.g. `device2` will be set to `false` if not set when calling the script?

Comment: exactly. If you want, you could also specify this using `-device2:$false` but you don't have to.

Comment: Check this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj554301.aspx and this http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-args.html for additional info